# What does pclean do?

Tags: command-line, pbuilder

I have looked everywhere for information on this... what does pclean do?

> The program 'pclean' is currently not installed. You can install it by
>   typing: `apt install pbuilder-scripts`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pclean` is just a wrapper for [`pbuilder --clean`](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/trusty/pbuilder-scripts/trusty/view/head:/pclean#L18), and from the manpage of pbuilder:

```
--clean
      Cleans   up   the   directory  specified  by  the  configuration
      BUILDPLACE and APTCACHE specified in /etc/pbuilderrc
```